# Не работает submit в jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Код не работает нигде - `console.log` не срабатывает внутри функции.

В чём ошибка?

```
$( "#form-login" ).submit(function( event ) {
    console.log('here');
    alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<form id="form-login" method="post">
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" name='login' type="email" id="login">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="login">Логин</label>
    </div>

    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" name='password' type="password" id="password">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="password">Пароль</label>
    </div>

    <div class="mdl-card__actions">
        <button type="submit" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button
            mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent buttons-login">Вход
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: сниппет в вопросе работает - выводится и в консоль и алерт, в чем проблема?

Comment: mybeer.info - исходный код. Не работает.

Comment: весь **необходимый** код должен быть непосредственно в вопросе, посмотрите как создать [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При правке заметил один лишний `</div>`,  в то время как в другом месте его не хватало. После правки кода всё заработало

```js
$( "#form-login" ).submit(function( event ) {
    console.log('here');
    alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<form id="form-login" method="post">
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" name='login' type="email" id="login">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="login">Логин</label>
    </div>

    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" name='password' type="password"
            id="password">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="password">Пароль</label>
    </div>

    <div class="mdl-card__actions">
        <button type="submit" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised
            mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent buttons-login">Вход
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

Вы указали ссылку [mybeer.info](http://mybeer.info)
Там не работает jquery, потому что нет `$(document).ready`

```html
<script>$(document).ready(function() { ... });</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, смогу - проверю. Проблема в том, что до этого в теге формы был onsubmit="" и все работало... Неожиданная проблема:(

Comment: Уточню: в хроме - будет. а в других браузерах нет.. Из-за чего и началась эпопея))

Comment: уточните пожалуйста, почему jquery код НЕ будет работать не в пределах этой обёртки? В моём понимании она просто откладывает выполнение js до момента полной прогрузки страницы. Или не так?
Просто хочется понять раз и навсегда)

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko, не обязательно использовать `ready`, он для работы при загрузки DOM. Если скрипт загружен в конце html документа, можно использовать `$(function() { ... }`

Comment: Еще раз спасибо)

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko, нужно отметить ответ как верный

Comment: жутко виноват. Везде исправлю сейчас)